# No - Scroll Page with extendable middle - part

Tags: html, css, flexbox, viewport

Let's say you have a page which you don't want to scroll, constisting of three parts; a header, a main part and a footer:

```
<body>
  <div id="page-content">
  <header>My Header</header>
  <main>Main Content</main>
  <div class="footer-pusher"></div>
  </div>
  <footer>My Header</footer>
</body>
```

The page shall always be 100% high, the header and the footer have a fix height and 100% width, and the middle part shall stretch to fill the rest of the page, having a min-width in case of simply to small screens in terms of height. Only in that case, the page shall be scrollable. To achieve this, I used the following CSS, including the one to have a sticky footer:

```
body, #page-content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.footer-pusher {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: -200px;
}

footer {
  height: 200px;
}

header {
  height: 125px;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 210px;
}
```

My question now is, how can I code via CSS that the `main` part expands to the remaining height of the page, and is at least 210px high? For illustrative purposes, I wrote the `flex-grow` property, as that's precisely the one I need, but in vertical and not in horizontal direction of the flexbox container. With the code above, the middle part is always 210px high..

Comment: `height: 100vh` for `#page-content`, and remove `flex` rules from `body`

Comment: cheers mate, just noticed the mistakes and got it working, did pretty much what you did. With one difference though; I've used ```height: 100%;``` for ```#page-content``` instead of ```vh```, and that worked too. Would you rather recommend one over the other? I've got the meta tag in the page's ```head``` who resizes responsively in terms of the viewport, so guess that's the reason why it worked too; lemme know what you'd prefer and why, if you may! Thanks again man!

Comment: I would not recommend styling the `body` tag except for some styling. It is better to remove all styles from the `body` and assign all `flex` rules with `height: 100vh` to `#page-content``.